# Google AppEngine, 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, floating-point

I'm trying to run my Google app engine application, there is a function I used to adjust polylines on the maps. I tested function on localhost, everything went well. But after I deployed the project, however:

```
'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

raised.

`'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cdotmap/streetcenterline.374700366610028884/handlers/mapdata.py", line 112, in get
    data["features"][i] = centerLine(data["features"][i])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cdotmap/streetcenterline.374700366610028884/functions.py", line 141, in centerLine
    lng, lat = point[0], point[1]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

which means I somehow the `point` become a `float` object and I can't access, the actually code is here:

```
points = []
points.append([0.2, 0.3])
points.append([0.5, 0.8])
```

I constructed a list of two lists, each list contains two float number, then I tried to assign it to something else like:

```
for point in points:
    lng, lat = point[0], point[1] #error pointing to this line
```

the error raised. this only happens when I deployed the application. Any clue here, anything would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: works for me, I think during runtime there is somewhere where the point is type of float instead of list of floats. Try put try catch and print the point.

Comment: thanks, I tried to catch the error, and was able to find a minor mismatch in the input data which makes point[1] a "None". but it should be "Nonetype" instead of "float"...weird, anyway, thanks for your suggestion..worked.